# How Oracle database instance knows his password file.

Tags: oracle

I want to clarify exactly how the database instance finds a password file? By name? Since the creation of the password file via the command orapwd we indicate only the SID in the file name. Or is there some kind of mechanism for the association database instance and the password file?

Can the situation that instance tries to access a file of passwords from another copy with remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'? Who keeps track?

Comment: I mean:
If in the initialization file parameter set REMOTE_LOGIN_PASSWORDFILE = 'exclusive'(only one instance of the database will be available to the password file), what happens when another instance tries to access this file password? Who controls(responsible for) access to the password file?

I understand how the access to the file in the OS. I understand the need to restrict access to the password file for other OS users.

But I do not understand who limit for the instance DB access to the password file (in the case of "EXCLUSIVE" and in the case of "SHARED").

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e17120/dba007.htm):

```
Required Password File Name and Locations.

UNIX and Linux:
Name: orapwORACLE_SID
Location: ORACLE_HOME/dbs

Windows:
Name: PWDORACLE_SID.ora
Location: ORACLE_HOME\database
```

Comment: Question is: If in the initialization file parameter set REMOTE_LOGIN_PASSWORDFILE = 'exclusive'(only one instance of the database will be available to the password file), what happens when another instance tries to access this file password? Who controls(responsible for) access to the password file? I understand how the access to the file in the OS. I understand the need to restrict access to the password file for other OS users. But I do not understand who limit for the instance DB access to the password file (in the case of "EXCLUSIVE" and in the case of "SHARED")